# IIS issue - website hosted on local machine not working

Tags: iis

For some reason I can't run website hosted with IIS on my local machine.
I've created a simple web application ("test"), with just index.htm, under the default Web Site.

I've confirmed IIS is working.

Following URLs do not work:

```
http://machine_name/test/
http://127.0.0.1/test/
http://localhost/test/
```

and this one works:

```
http://[::1]/test/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your machine is forced into IPV6 mode. Go into your network adapter settings and try disabling IPV6 or changing the priority.

Also look into changing the `HOSTS` file. Adding the line `127.0.0.1 localhost` should fix the issue.